# Is it possible to mock a webservice on a remote server with Protractor?

Tags: angularjs, web-services, mocking, protractor, e2e-testing

For a project, I need to write some tests with Protractor on an application which is on a remote server (i.e. not on local).

I try to mock a call to a webservice in order to obtain a unique response. I can't obtain any result, using addMockModule method or the module httpbackend.

So my question is : is it possible to mock the response of a remote server with Protractor ? Or, is it only possible on a local server ?

Thanks,

Marine

Comment: Any idea ? It would be a great help for me.